# Finding file locations in offline softwares in C

Tags: c, file, offline

At some point in my C program I have to deal with something like this.

```
FILE * fptr = fopen("/Parent/child/.../file.dat");
```

Which means in order to access any file I need to know it's location. That's all understandable.
But, how can I make this generic? In my computer "/Parent/child/.../file.dat" will work because that's where the file is stored, but I'm making a software to distribute to other users so the path obviously differs. My question is, how can I install a specific file into the user's computer such that I can know and get the location of that file. I a but confused about this concept so any resources that could help me understand it better would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use command line arguements and pass the path, any problem?

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand the point, but the user should just click on some application icon and run it, I don't expect anyone to run the program through command line and pass the appropriate arguments for file locations.

Comment: The methods are OS-dependent.

Comment: Yes. Is there a source where I can learn about this specifically linux for example. I've tried but found it hard to find any useful ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux the default path to application files should be *hardcoded*. There is a [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) which applications should follow. For example, architecture-independent files should go to `/usr/share/` and then either your application name or, if you expect the data to be shared between applications, a generic category such as `images`. User-specific configuration files should go `$HOME/.config/<app-name>`. Older applications place their default configuration in `$HOME/.<app-name>` instead.

You should also provide an ability to override the default path to the data with a command line switch and/or an environment variable and/or a user configuration file (the location of the latter should also be overridable with a command line switch and/or an environment variable).

Some applications search for their data directory relatively to the executable position. An executable can know its own absolute path by reading `/proc/self/exe` symbolic link. For example, if an executable finds itself in `/usr/local/bin/somename`, it can look for `/usr/local/share/<app-name>` (two levels up from the executable name and down to `share/<app-name>`.).

Finally, if you distribute source code for the users to build, the file locations should be configuration parameters.